# Python: How to explode column of dictionaries into columns with matching keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key-value

I have a column in pandas dataframe that has the following structure (see example). I think I have a nested dictionary in a single column, and I want each key to have it's own column. I want all the matching keys to be the same column. Run the examples for more details

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = ["{'age': 59, 'gender': 'Female','pain': 'No', 'date': '2022-09-29'}",
       "{'gender': 'Male', 'date': '2022-10-11'}",
       "{'age': 18, 'date': '2022-10-11', 'pain': 'No'}",
       ]

original_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['test'])
original_df.head()
```

I want to explode the dataframe so that it has the following structure:

```
data = [[59,'Female','No','2022-09-29'], [np.nan,'Male',np.nan,'2022-10-11'], [18,np.nan,'2022-10-11','No']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['age','gender','date','pain'])
desired_df.head()
```

Comment: Your "data" consists of strings of dict representations. "ast.literal_eval" can help to convert them to real dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [json.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd


original_df["test"] = original_df["test"].apply(literal_eval)
df = original_df.join(pd.json_normalize(original_df.pop("test")))
print(df)

    age  gender pain        date
0  59.0  Female   No  2022-09-29
1   NaN    Male  NaN  2022-10-11
2  18.0     NaN   No  2022-10-11
```